# How to refactor code that contains multiple divs with same class in reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to have same appearance for all notification messages. I have a parent component for which two child components render different messages...one normal message and other component displays message based on context.

Below is the code,

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.element = document.createElement('div');
        this.element.className= 'wrapper';
}

componentDidMount() {
    root.appendChild(this.element);
}}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
render = () => {
    return (
        <div onClick={this.close} className="notification_info">
           soemthing
        </div>);}}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
    render = () => {
         <div>
             <h2>Debug</h2>          
        </div>}
        let content;
         if (content) {
             return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="main">
                        <div className="notification">
                            <div className="notification_info">{content} 
                            </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div className="close"><SvgClose width="28" /></div>
            </div>);}}}
```

I want to create three divs with className container, main, notification for both child1 and child2 components as well. I want to add the same divs like in child2 to child1 as well before div with classname notification_info.

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="main">
        <div className="notification">
```

What i tried doing is creating three divs with classname container, main, notification for child1 component as well. This would create container for normal and contextual messages as well. But then i am looking for some other way to do it. refactor it or clean way of doing it.

Could someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please reduce your example and present a code snippet which do not contain unrelated parts. You can find hints here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

What about making the notification a standalone component? In this way you wouldn't have that much div nesting on a single component.